# Error when i want to export as FBX

Tags: export, .fbx

I work on a face for FIFA 22. I've done multiple face before in the same working process. Suddenly i get these error messages while i tryna export the head as FBX.

Could someone maybe help me? Thanks!

[image: error messages PS]

Comment: I have no experience with this sort of thing, but the error basically says that it's expecting "tris/quads", so would applying a Triangulate modifier before trying to export to make sure there are no n-gons work?

Comment: Yes, thank you! I had to do it, for the eyes. CTL + T and then i could export it! Thanks!